# Remaking the same application with the same package name and publishing it

Tags: android, package

Title sounds funny, but here we go:

One month ago I made my first application, lets call it *"app1"*, which was basically just me learning. Now, after making another app, I want to remake my first application *"app1"*, because I know I can do it now much better.

Remaking it in its current state seems quite impossible for me, so I came up with an idea to just make a new project and implement my code there.

If I start a new project in android studio, give the same package name, use the same key store and everything else, if I upload the new apk file, will it be accepted as an update? Or do I have to work with the old project?

Thanks!

Comment: @Abhishek I think it will be accepted, why should he work with old project?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple apps in the play store with the same display name, but they have to have different package names (and the play store won't actually allow a second app with the same package name as another even to be uploaded)

Comment: You don't have to work with old project ... with same package name and same key you can override the app in store ... so obviously for the question ***will it be accepted as an update?*** an answer is **yes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as apk has same applicationId and is signed with the same key, it will be considered as valid update on Google Play. Of course, you'll need to increment version code number.

Comment: Makes sense, as there shouldn't be anything else besides package name and key from stopping it.